# Add logo to javadoc to top left corner using doclava

Tags: java, gradle, doclet

I am trying to generate javadoc using doclava and need to add logo/image to top left corner of javadoc.
I could manage to add project name but struggling with logo.

```
task generateJavadoc(type: Javadoc) {
        title = null
        ext.assetsDir = new File(projectDir,"/assets")
        description "Generate html Javadoc for " + project.name.capitalize()
        source = variant.javaCompile.source
        ext.androidJar = "${android.sdkDirectory}/platforms/${android.compileSdkVersion}/android.jar"
        options.docletpath = configurations.jaxDoclet.files.asType(List)
        options.doclet "com.google.doclava.Doclava"
        classpath = files(variant.javaCompile.classpath.files) + files(ext.androidJar)
        options.addStringOption('hdf project.name',project.name.capitalize())
        options.addStringOption('templatedir',assetsDir.toString())
        exclude '**/BuildConfig.java'
        exclude '**/R.java'
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In your customizations.css you can add background for the header class - 
background: url('../assets/images/image.png') no-repeat 0 50%;